# Tracking ChangeEvent source in collaborative maps

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have a collaborative map, with collaborative maps as values. When an event happens on the value maps, I want to know to which key (of the outer map) the event belongs. Anyone can suggest a clean way of achieving this?

CMap(key, cmapb(k,string)) , ChangeEvent happens on cmapb string, I want to know key of CMap. k is unique only for individual key(so tracking k and then finding key which contains k is not an option).

[ValueChangedEvent](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.ValueChangedEvent) [CollaborativeMap](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.CollaborativeMap)

Edit:

I am attaching the EventListener this way before adding records(cmapb) to CMAP:

```
records.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUE_CHANGED, updateJSON);
```

> If I could pass the id of records on updateJSON, I could then iterate
>   through CMAP to find which value has that id. Although I do not know
>   how I can pass the id, as well as the ChangeEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to model here.  Are you actually adding arbitrary elements to these maps?  Otherwise, you might look at using custom objects, where you could have a field for the key and other fields for the other objects you are storing.  (See https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/build-model#lifecycle_of_a_custom_collaborative_data_object)

If you really just want to have access to that value in the function, you can do that with a standard javascript, e.g closure, or a [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function.

Comment: Just now I thought I can add the name of Key on the k, and then extract it from event.property. I was very focused in getting a different solution and couldnt see this simple one. Regardless I will look into your suggestions.